# Deep linking issue when the app is open in background react native

Tags: react-native, deep-linking

I am facing an issue related to deep linking in react native. Deep linking is implemented for both ios and android. I am using deep linking to confirm user's account. User click on *confirm my account* on email sent to him which should ideally redirect him back to the application. Upon clicking the confirmation link, it does redirect it to the app.
If the app is closed, everything works fine and the user gets confirmed. But the issue is that if the app is already open, upon redirecting, it does not confirm the user.
This is my code that I have written in main entry file (`App.js`)

```
useEffect(() => {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then(url => {
      if (url == null) {
        return;
      } else {
        handleDeepLink(url);
      }
    });
    let subcribtion = Linking.addEventListener('url', handleDeepLink);
    subcribtion.subscriber;

    return () => {
      subcribtion.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Here is my implementation in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<intent-filter  >
                <data android:scheme="com.sensights" android:host="open" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter  >
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" android:label="stage01.random.ai">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="stage01.random.ai"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                 />
                <data android:scheme="https" android:host="stage01.random.ai"
                    android:pathPrefix="/"
                 />
            </intent-filter>
```

I also tried using `App State` from react native. But the issue with it is when comes on the foreground, `Linking.getInitialURL()` returns `null`.
My react native version is `0.70.5`, react-navigation version is `4.4.4` and I am using universal links as deep linking approach.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I was trying to confirm user account via deep linking but was unable to confirm user when the app was in background

Comment: Any update on this, facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

```
useEffect(() => {
    Linking.getInitialURL()
      .then((url) => {
        console.log("uuu", url);
        if (url !== null) {
          // if opened from notification if app is killed
        }
      }).catch((err) => console.error("An error occurred", err));

    let subcribtion = Linking.addEventListener("url", handleOpenURL);
    subcribtion.subscriber;

    return () => {
      subcribtion.remove();
    };
  }, []);
  // Linking.addEventListener('url', handleOpenURL);

  function handleOpenURL(evt) {
    // Will be called when the notification is pressed foreground
    console.log(evt.url);
    // do something
  }
```